# UITableViewController not working as a delegate for another VC?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm quite new to the iOS SDK, but I've been trying to use a UITableViewController as a delegate for another VC. The problem is part of a bigger application but I simplified it below, where I try having the UITableViewController dismiss the second VC once "Done" is pressed on the second VC.

**MainViewController.h (UITableViewController)**

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "SecondViewController.h"

    @interface MainViewController : UITableViewController <SecondViewControllerDelegate>
    @end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void)doneEditing {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**SecondViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SecondViewController;
@protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)doneEditing;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SecondViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;
@end
```

**SecondViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [self.delegate doneEditing];
}
```

It works if the Main is not a UITableViewController. I've noticed that the "Done" is recognized when touched, but the "doneEditing" method is never called.

Comment: Did you set the table view controller as the delegate of SecondViewController?

Comment: Yes, as is shown in MainViewController.h. I've worked with delegates before but for some reason it hasn't been working out with a UITableViewController.

Comment: Adding a property isn't the same as setting the delegate instance at runtime. I suspect that if you set a breakpoint at `[self.delegate doneEditing]`, you'll find that `self.delegate` is actually nil.

Comment: No, what you show is just a "promise" to the compiler that you will implement the protocol, that doesn't set the delegate.

Comment: Also, you can now use `[[self presentingViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` for just a case like this. Unless, of course, `doneEditing` will do more than simply dismiss the modal view controller.

Comment: @rdelmar, Thanks for the clarification. How would I go about setting it as the delegate?

Comment: You set yourself as delegate when you create an instance of SecondViewController just before you present it. So if your instance is called secondVC, then secondVC.delegate = self;

Comment: @mbm29414 You're right, self.delegate is nil. And yes, in my other application I'm trying to send some data along with dismissing it. But if there is no delegate, I guess that's the bigger problem.

Comment: So, either try my (non-delegate) solution, or follow @EddieK's advice and set the delegate in code when creating the modal/child/whatever view controller. A `nil` variable isn't a problem, just an opportunity to find what you overlooked.

Comment: @rdelmar It works now. Thanks a lot! You're welcome to set your comment as an answer. Now I'm wondering how my other projects worked without me doing that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, you should use an unwind segue. It is an easy way to dismiss a modal `UIViewController` without delegation. [Here is a good tutorial on unwind segues](http://pragmaticstudio.com/blog/2013/2/5/unwind-segues)